# failing to use .nextSibling

Tags: javascript

i am trying to select the next td and add a class to it by using nextSibling but it doesn't seem to work.

```
const player2pos = document.querySelector("#player2-race .active");
player2pos.nextSibling.classList.add("active");
```

what i get:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined
at HTMLDocument.

when i console.log(document.querySelector("#player2-race .active")), it shows that i selected the right td. can someone tell me what i am doing wrong?

EDIT: here is the html

```
        <tr id="player2-race">
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td class="active"></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
```

Comment: You should show some html too. Maybe you are selecting the last element of that row?

Comment: @arieljuod it is currently the 4th element (of 12)

Comment: @imvain2 yes! thanks a million

Comment: Oh I get it, use `.nextElementSibling` instead of `.nextSibling`. The former returns the next HTML element, the later returns the next element (which in this case is the new line character)